# How to get the usage for an storage account in Microsoft azure using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

How to get the **usage** for an storage account in Microsoft azure using powershell.

I am able to get the storage accounts present in an subscription. But these variables are not exposing any methods by which i can get the usage of an storage account.

Comment: By **usage** do you mean total size of the storage account or something else?

Comment: By usage i mean, the Total usage of the storage account

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Usage could mean different things. It could mean how much data is stored in a storage account or it could also mean how much data stored in that storage account is actually used (we could have blobs in a storage account that are never used). The answer would depend on what kind of usage statistics you're looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I need to know how much data is stored in the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way (afaik) would be to enable Storage analytics metrics on the storage account and then fetch and aggregate on the logs.

Example (enable metric on Blob)

```
Set-StorageServicePropertiesForAnalytics -ServiceName "Blob" -StorageAccountName "<Storage Account Name>" -StorageAccountKey "<Storage Account Key>" -MetricsEnabled -MetricsRetentionPolicyDays 7 -MetricsRetentionPolicyEnabled
```

NB: You have to wait for a while (a day) after enabling the log

Then aggregate (and fetch the usage on the storage account after a day or so):

```
$logName = "C:\tmp\StorageAccount.log"; 
Get-StorageAnalyticsMetrics -DataType "Capacity" -ServiceName "Blob" -LocalPath $logName -StorageAccountName "<StoragE account name"> -StorageAccountKey "<Storage account key>" 
$results = (Import-Csv $logName | Where-Object { $_.Category -eq "data" } | Select-Object -Last 1 @{Name="AccountName";Expression={"My storage account"}}, Time, "Capacity (bytes)", "Container count", "Object count")

$results
```

Should give you a data set which is easy to display and aggregate on. You could also iterate multiple storage accounts / containers and split this if you want. 
This example only fetches for the blob service. You can also get storage analytics used for other services (table/queue etc); however as specified in the documentation the capacity metric is only available for the blob storage.

For more information on storage account analytics and options see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343258.aspx

Please note that after enabling the analytics on the Storage account, you'll have to wait before exporting the logs and aggregating on the data.

Comment: Storage analytics capacity would only work for blobs though. Not for tables & queues.

Comment: True. It would be documented on the log-format from the documentation I referred to. I'll update my answer to make it clear. Not sure he's interested in only blob usage or trying to calculate the data/usage of Queues & Table storage in addition as his response to the comments is fairly vague.

Comment: I would like to know the overall storage usage of an storage account.
My Input will be like subscription name and storage account.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have tried the command (Set-StorageServicePropertiesForAnalytics), i couldn't find it in azure module. do we need to install any specific modules for that?